# Nesting Java Inner Classes

Tags: java, class, nested

How can I instantiate class C if it is nested within class B, and class B in again nested within class A?

```
class A {
    class B {
        class C {
            ..............
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To instantiate `C`, you will need an enclosing instance of `B`, which in turn will need an enclosing instance of `A`.

```
A someA = new A();
B someB = a.new B();
C someC = b.new C();
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it

```
A.B.C c = new A().new B().new C();
```

You can concatenate the new() lines if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate like this.

```
A a = new A();
A.B b = a.new B();
A.B.C c = b.new C();
```

This works..

```
public class InnerClassTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A.B b = a.new B();
        A.B.C c = b.new C();
        c.setValue(100);
        System.out.println("Innermost value " + c.getValue());
    }
}
class A {
    class B {
        class C {
            int value;

            public int getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public void setValue(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the classes do not functionally rely on being nested, i.e. `class C` does not refer to methods and/or fields of `class B` or `class A` then you could make the inner classes static.

```
class A {
    static class B {
        static class C {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

you can then create them from wherever you like:

```
A.B.C c = new A.B.C ();
```